# Share folders via files sync

Tags: sync, files

I need to share multiples files organized in folder structure. If and how is that possible with with files sync? 
So people can sync multiple files organized in at certain structure.

I dont find any sharing settings on the folders only on the individual assets.

Thanks in advance.
Best,
Andreas

Answer (score -1):

I saw an article on this subject a few minutes ago.  From what I have seen so far, this is a feature request.

Comment: Please provide links particularly to a feature request that can be voted for.  See [answer]

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SFSE and thanks for your contribution to the discussion. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [answer]. As it stands, this answer is too vague to help the community much. Can you add more detail and links to support your claim?